# Multiple fonts in single metapost page-sized figure

Tags: fonts, context, metapost

I have a MetaPost figure created in ConTeXt as follows:

```
\starttext
\startMPpage
  draw textext("Foo") shifted (2cm,2cm) ;
  draw textext("Bar") shifted (5cm,5cm) ;
  % just to show my figure is supposed to span over all paper size:
  draw unitsquare xyscaled (21cm,29.7cm) ; % A4 paper size
\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

I'd like to set a different font for "Foo" and "Bar".

I've come across several wiki pages/tutorials explaining how to change font *between* two figures, but I've not been able to find how to switch *within a single figure*.

Comment: Could you make your script compilable?

Comment: It compiles for me. What error(s) are you facing?

Comment: I'm new to these scripts, so I thought they were snippets, sorry.

Comment: @Silverspur You are starting with MetaPost, great! Recommended reading: https://github.com/thruston/Drawing-with-Metapost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run

```
\starttext
\startMPpage
  draw textext(btex \it Foo etex) shifted (2cm,2cm) ;
  draw textext(btex \bf Bar etex) shifted (5cm,5cm) ;
  % just to show my figure is supposed to span over all paper size:
  draw unitsquare xyscaled (21cm,29.7cm) ; % A4 paper size
\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

on the [online ConTeXt engine](https://live.contextgarden.net), I get

[image]

Comment: You don't actually *need* the `btex` .. `etex`.  You can put Context formatting commands in a string:  so this works: `draw textext("\it Foo")`

Comment: or even `for i=1 upto 5: draw textext("$p_" & decimal i & "$") shifted (20i, 42); endfor`

Comment: Oh this is actually obvious. I did not think one could put TeX commands inside the textext parentheses.